# obtener numero de dias transcurridos

Tags: java

quiero hacer un método en donde me ingresa un LocalDate y me devuelve el numero de días transcurridos, primeramente lo estoy realizando en la clase principal para ir viendo si estoy de acorde con la l{ogica, resultados y más cosas que se debe tener en cuenta cuando se opera fechas pero ya me confundí un poco cuando la fecha que ingreso de parámetro es mayor a la fecha actual que utilizo para realizar los cálculos.

```
    LocalDate fecha1=LocalDate.of(1990,8,18);
    LocalDate fecha2=LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("fech1: "+fecha1);
    System.out.println("fech2: "+fecha2);

    int anioACT = fecha2.getYear();
    int mesACT = fecha2.getMonthValue();
    int diaACT = fecha2.getDayOfMonth();

    int resAnio = 0;

    int resDia = fecha2.getDayOfMonth() - fecha1.getDayOfMonth() + 1;
    int resMes = fecha2.getMonthValue() - fecha1.getMonthValue() -1;

    if(fecha2.getYear() > fecha1.getYear()) {
       if(fecha2.getMonthValue() == fecha1.getMonthValue()) {


                if(fecha2.getDayOfMonth() == fecha1.getDayOfMonth()) {
                    resAnio = fecha2.getYear() - fecha1.getYear();
                }
            }else {
                resAnio = fecha2.getYear() - fecha1.getYear() - 1;
            }
        }                                                   

        System.out.println("dias: "+resDia);
        System.out.println("meses: "+resMes);
        System.out.println("anios: "+resAnio);
```

a los días luego de la operación entre ellos le sumo 1 ya que quiero que ese día también forme parte del resultado; en caso de que el mes ingresado sea mayor a el mes actual pensaba en restarle la diferencia que existe para que se cumpla un mes y también restarle un mes a los meses ingresados.

Me pueden ayudar a dar encontrar una solución factible. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una respuesta que te puede valer es añadir la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
System.out.println("Entre las dos fechas han pasado: " + fecha1.until(fecha2, ChronoUnit.DAYS) + " dias");
```

con `until` calculas el periodo de tiempo desde una fecha a otra.
Como parametros recibe la fecha con la que quieres comparar y la unidad que quieres como salida, también le he añadido el + 1 que deseabas.

Un ejemplo con tu codigo:

> Entre las dos fechas han pasado: 10572 dias

¡Espero que te haya servido!

Answer (score 1):

una forma de calcularlo tambien es usando la clase Period de la siguiente forma...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LocalDate a = LocalDate.now().minusDays(5);
        LocalDate b = LocalDate.now();

        System.out.println(Period.between(a,b).getDays());
    }
}
```

Period para unidades mayores o iguales a dias (dias, meses, años...).

Si requiere mas adelante calcular unidades menores o iguales a dias (horas, minutos, segundos...) puede usar la clase Duration.

Comment: Ante todo bienvenido a la comunidad ! Y si, es cierto, no se me había ocurrido esa manera y además es interesante tener en cuenta esa clase, gracias :D !